# Searchlight Simple Optics Problem

Tags: optics, lenses, light-emitting-diodes

Here is my problem.  I want to make a working model of a searchlight.

I can't sensibly make a parabolic reflector at this scale so I planned to place a small 0201 LED  (0.6 x 0.4mm) in the body of the search light and place a cheap convex lens on the end at a distance f from the LED.  I have a couple of short focus plano-convex lenses f about 15 to 20mm taken from wide angle door veiwers.

In my simple mind and from my memory of physics 45 years ago if I put a nearly point source of light at the focal length from the lens I should get a columnated beam.

It doesn't work!  I just get light scattered randomly and can't get any sort of beam.

Is there something special about the cheap plastic plano-convex lenses used in a door viewer?
Does it matter if I put it flat side toward or away from the LED? (I thought toward ought to be better).
Do I need to use a convex-convex lens?
Is there a source of better cheap lenses I can use for these models?

Have they changed the laws of optics in the last 45 years or am I just not remembering something?

Plan B  I'm continuing my search for a cheap torch with a parabolic reflector of about the right size I can canibalise but they all seem to produce at least a 30degree beam.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pictures of your setup and the resulting light emission would help.

Comment: The curved side should be oriented to the parallel beam, in your case outwards, to minimize spherical abberations. What is the angle of the led, the diameter of the lens, and f?

Comment: To clarify my specific request is if anyone can shed light on what I'm doing wrong given my rusty optics knowledge.

Comment: See the picture, so far it's just an LED and Lens held on some blutac. As you can see the lens is producing a difuse halo of light with a few brighter arcs.

Comment: Thank you Charles, that's what I suspected.  The LED is very wide angle, about 120 degrees (most surface mount LEDs are as they have no lens body like a panel mount LED has).  The lenses are 12 or 18mm diameter. f about 15mm or 20mm. determined simply by getting the best focus I could of the sun on a piece of paper before it caught fire (optics is fun!).

Comment: Doesn't look like I can upload a picture but it's nothing more than holding the LED at a distance from the lens.

Comment: I have got to the bottom of this problem with some help from a local fellow model (railways not catwalk) maker.

Comment: The lenes I have aren't plano-convex, the face I thought was flat is slightly concave.  They also don't have a simple focus.  The profile is some sort of elipse so it doesn't produce a single focal point.  I guess it's something to do with them being very wide angle lenses and it somehow gets compensated by the eyepiece lens that I wasn't using.